# Facebook messenger bot showing card images on web but not on mobile

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing facebook bot using Microsoft bot framework & have a strange issue: I return card carousel with thumbnail images. When talking from the web, I get all images, when from android, I get only 1 or 2 images. Dimensions are same, images are returned by my own services, all are png.

Any ideas where to look for problems?

**Update - Issue Fixed**

So turns out, I messed up with Content-Length header in my image handler service and was sending incorrect length with images. After fixing it, everything works as expected. Still, it's interesting, why some images were showing up even with incorrect length header and some not.

Answer (score 1):

Please, ensure the images you sent are httpS instead of http. This is a like a assumption in the documentation. 
If you use http, its shown in the emulator but not in other secure channels like Skype and Facebook.

Comment: I found the issue (see updated question) but your answer is also makes sense.